# ActionMailer template + text

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Our app lets users customize the emails. However, we'd still like to use a template layout that surrounds the customized email. I read the Rails [ActionMailer guideline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-layouts) but still can't figure it out.

```
mail(
    :to => 'blahblah@example.com',
    :subject => 'Email Subject',
    :content_type => "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
) do |format|
  format.html { render layout: 'mailer', text: 'Hello' }
end
```

I'm trying to use the `mailer` layout and include text `Hello` within it. This code doesn't work. I think I'm missing something simple but can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you have a mailer view created already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```rb
mail(
  :to => 'blahblah@example.com',
  :subject => 'Email Subject',
  :content_type => "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
) do |format|
  @text = 'Hello'
  format.html { render layout: 'mailer' }
end
```

Then in your mailer.html.erb file:

```rb
<%= @text %>
```

Comment: Wow. that was fast and awesome. I can't believe I didn't think about that. Thanks.